# Data model line pointing to itself

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, inner-join, self-join

I am learning SQl on microsoft learn.
During an exercise Microsoft provided a datamodel. On the bottom Right there is a line with a key pointing to itself. What does that mean?

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That image is too tiny to see anything, but I presume that it represents a foreign key which references a column that belongs to the same table.

For example, `mgr_id` is a *manager* of an employee identified by `emp_id`. There's also a foreign key from `mgr_id` to `emp_id` which means that database will take care about valid values in `mgr_id` column, i.e. you won't be able to insert `ID` that doesn't exist in `employees.emp_id` column.

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
   emp_id   NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
   name     VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
   salary   NUMBER,
   mgr_id   NUMBER REFERENCES employees (emp_id)
);
```

ER model (generated by TOAD GUI tool):

[image]

---

**[EDIT]**

Now that image is enlarged, yes - it seems that `ParentProductCategoryID` references `ProductCategoryID` (explanation remains the same).

Comment: I have updated my image. Let me read again your comment to understand

Comment: Right; see edited answer, please. Say if you need further explanation.

Comment: I understand! Since mgr id is always an employee is, it is not possible to insert an id which is not an employee right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.